# Python ProcessPool and Pandas read_sql

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing

I Have a script which needs to fetch data from a DB day by day and for different reporting scenarios, for a better performance I tried Threading and Multi Processing but seem to get stuck at the same step every time.

Inside my Thread/Process (doesn't matter for this scenario, tried both), I have this loop fetching me my data from the db (works flawlessly in my non-parallel version):

```
def task(date_list, _report):
   ...Create the DB Connection etc...
        for date in date_list:
            log.info(f"Fetching Data for XYZ: {date}")
            df_tmp = fetch_report(_date=date, connection=db_con)
            df = df.append(df_tmp)
```

Inside the fetch_report function it shows me the first print and then immediately seems to jump out of the execution as well as the process/thread itself (it won't even continue with the outer loop)

```
....
print(f"Selecting Data")
sql = f"""
...
"""

df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=connection)
print(df)
```

Thats how I call my tasks:

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    task1 = executor.submit(task, date_list, 'example_report1')
    task2 = executor.submit(task, date_list, 'example_report2')
    task3 = executor.submit(task, date_list, 'example_report3')
    task4 = executor.submit(task, date_list, 'example_report4')
```

Thankful for any hints!

Comment: Not really enough info to go on here... My first step would be to skip `Concurrent.futures`, and try to just see if `task` works in a `multiprocessing.Process`. Not even in parallel, just to determine if you have a problem with running from another process.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, your hint brought the solution, acutally there was an error in the sql (depends on a date and it was wrongly formatted). When you run a Process or Threadpool it just swallows the exception!? When you run it via the multiprocessing library it won't, very peculiar...

Comment: You have to check the returned `Future` object's [`exception()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.exception) to see if an exception was raised. `Executor.map` automatically re-raises exceptions, but not `submit`. `Concurrent.futures` is a higher level library on top of `multiprocessing`, and has more built-in error handling. `mp.Process` has no error handling at all, and the child process is simply allowed to print it's error to stderr, and exit. If you want error handling with that, you have to do it yourself (which isn't always bad)